# Unable to call custom method

Tags: django-models

I am newbie at Django.  I have model with a custom method.  In view I am 
retrieving a single object.

Here is my code -- My model

```
class Problem(models.Model): 
    problem = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    solution=models.CharField(max_length=500) 
    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.problem 
   def retrieve_rankdata(self): 
                return self.problem.split()[0].split('/')
```

in view I am doing this

```
def show(request): 
       problem = Problem.objects.all()[0] 
        t1=problem.retrieve_rankdata()
```

But, I am getting this error 
'Problem' object has no attribute 'retrieve_rankdata'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell, but the problem could be with your indentation. The indentation in the code you've pasted is inconsistent, so it wouldn't work properly anyway - I suspect in your actual code, `def retrieve_rankdata` is a couple more spaces to the left.

Don't forget that Python uses indentation to tell whether or not an attribute or a method is part of a class. So if your `def retrieve_rankdata` line is not actually indented at the same level as the `def __unicode__` one, it won't be considered part of the `Problem` class.

Comment: Man, you were rite.wasted so much time.I was using notepad++.Then,edited using IDLE, and it showed the indentation issue.